# Who are the parents of lord Sai Baba?

Tags: sai

I listened to many stories of lord Sai Baba.

Who are the parents of Sai Baba?

Comment: Can you specify which Sai Baba you're referring to? Shirdi or Sathya?

Comment: @USer345738380 No...They are different...Check on Google.

Answer (score 1):

His parents were Hindu. His father was a Brahmin, his mother accompanied him. The story is she left him near a river and prayed to God to take care of him. He was founded by a Muslim family who didn't have child so they  that he is a godsend child for them and took care him.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. We have a policy of insisting a reference for answers posted on this site. Please add references to your answer like which book contains this information etc., see [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/5212) and [answer].

Answer (score 1):

The official web site of Sri Shirdi [Sai Sansthan](https://www.sai.org.in/en/history) says no such information is available as to the details of the parents of Sri Sai.

> Nobody knew the parents, birth or birthplace of Sai Baba. Many
>   inquiries were made, many questions were put to Baba and others
>   regarding these details, but no convincing answer or information has
>   yet been obtained. Practically we know nothing about these matters.
>   When asked about his relatives and other details he gave only one
>   answer:'From very long'.

Comment: I think it was pretty clear reason to hide his whereabouts in order to bring Islam in Maratha community. Because they were hardcore Hindus those days and only way was Sai Baba.